# (php) Is there a way to know the string length in terms of "spaces" occupied on stdout?

Tags: php, string, spaces, strlen

I need to know how many "spaces" a string is occupying when printed on stdout.

So, as example

```
<?
function customlength($input) {
    echo $input . "(" . strlen($input) . ")\n";
}
echo customlength("Stefano");
echo customlength("Stefano\t\t1");
echo str_repeat("---------+", 3) . "\n";
?>
```

is getting me that the 2 string are 7 and 10 characters long, but they took 7 and 17 "spaces" on stdout

```
Stefano(7)
Stefano         1(10)
---------+---------+---------+
```

So expectation is instead to get

```
Stefano(7)
Stefano         1(17)
---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: I would think that one tab = 4 spaces in a terminal

Comment: A TAB is one character.  If you want 4 spaces then add 4 spaces.

Comment: A tab is one character when it comes to ASCII, but when printed out, it can depend on the settings of where it's printed. For instance, in HTML it's still one space. Terminal, I think the default is usually 4 but some people may change their tabs to be 2 spaces.

Comment: The issue is not only related to TAB character but even to special character to enable colors, blinking... In those case the string passed to enable and disable them does not impact on the shown string length. Anyway and from your answer I should understand that the answer is "No. This is not possible."